# Replace Validation Monitors with tf.train.SessionRunHook when using Estimators

Tags: validation, tensorflow

I am running a DNNClassifier, for which I am monitoring accuracy while training. monitors.ValidationMonitor from contrib/learn has been working great, in my implementation I define it:

```
validation_monitor = skflow.monitors.ValidationMonitor(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(A_test, Cl2_test), eval_steps=1, every_n_steps=50)
```

and then use call from:

```
clf.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(A, Cl2),
            steps=1000, monitors=[validation_monitor])
```

where:

```
clf = tensorflow.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(...
```

This works fine. That said, validation monitors appear to be deprecated and a similar functionality to be replaced with `tf.train.SessionRunHook`.

I am a newbie in TensorFlow, and it does not seem trivial to me how such a replacing implementation would look like. Any suggestion are highly appreciated. Again, I need to validate the training after a specific number of steps.
Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: I'm about to discover if it helps me or not, but I found this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7669#issuecomment-281519985

Comment: I haven't found a good solution. The problem is I am unable to access the training metrics returned by the model function from within the SessionRunHook, which is needed to monitor the metrics. ValidationMonitor is deprecated but still available. I am continuing to use it until a better solution is available.

Answer (score 17):

There's an undocumented utility called [`monitors.replace_monitors_with_hooks()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py#L1214) which converts monitors to hooks. The method accepts (i) a list which may contain both monitors and hooks and (ii) the Estimator for which the hooks will be used, and then returns a list of hooks by wrapping a SessionRunHook around each Monitor.

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import monitors as monitor_lib

clf = tf.estimator.Estimator(...)

list_of_monitors_and_hooks = [tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(...)]
hooks = monitor_lib.replace_monitors_with_hooks(list_of_monitors_and_hooks, clf)
```

This isn't really a *true* solution to the problem of fully replacing the ValidationMonitor—we're just wrapping it up with a non-deprecated function instead. However, I can say this has worked for me so far in that it maintained all the functionality I need from the ValidationMonitor (i.e. evaluating every *n* steps, early stopping using a metric, etc.)

One more thing—to use this hook you'll need to update from a `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator` (which only accepts monitors) to the more full-fledged and official [`tf.estimator.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) (which only accepts hooks). So, you should instantiate your classifier as a `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier`, and train using its method `train()` instead (which is just a re-naming of `fit()`):

```
clf = tf.estimator.Estimator(...)

...

clf.train(
    input_fn=...
    ...
    hooks=hooks)
```

Answer (score 4):

I managed to come up with a way to extend `tf.train.SessionRunHook` as suggested.

```
import tensorflow as tf


class ValidationHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    def __init__(self, model_fn, params, input_fn, checkpoint_dir,
                 every_n_secs=None, every_n_steps=None):
        self._iter_count = 0
        self._estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
            model_fn=model_fn,
            params=params,
            model_dir=checkpoint_dir
        )
        self._input_fn = input_fn
        self._timer = tf.train.SecondOrStepTimer(every_n_secs, every_n_steps)
        self._should_trigger = False

    def begin(self):
        self._timer.reset()
        self._iter_count = 0

    def before_run(self, run_context):
        self._should_trigger = self._timer.should_trigger_for_step(self._iter_count)

    def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
        if self._should_trigger:
            self._estimator.evaluate(
                self._input_fn
            )
            self._timer.update_last_triggered_step(self._iter_count)
        self._iter_count += 1
```

and used it as a `training_hook` in `Estimator.train`:

```
estimator.train(input_fn=_input_fn(...),
                steps=num_epochs * num_steps_per_epoch,
                hooks=[ValidationHook(...)])
```

It doesn't have any fancy things a `ValidationMonitor` has like early-stopping and whatnot but this should be a start.

Comment: How does this stay up to date with the latest trained parameters when the estimator is built during `__init__` ?  Is it able to stay up to date by looking for changes/latest files added to `checkpoint_dir` before it runs `evaluate()` ?

Comment: @StephenWylie I think the `model_dir` is addressing what you asked, my question is how do you stop the training in the hook if you find the validation score starts to drop? Or you just log the best performing model...

Comment: @LYu that hook I made does not have early stopping-stopping yet. So for now, it just runs training and validation until it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#train
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/CheckpointSaverListener

I use the checkpoint save listener to monitor the training, the estimator you use likely to have a parameter called `saving_listeners`. It gets called every time a checkpoint is created and that is a parameter you can set in the `config` of your estimator. So the hook is:

```
class ValidationListener(tf.train.CheckpointSaverListener):
    def __init__(self, estimator, input_fn):
        self._estimator = estimator
        self._input_fn = input_fn
        self._evaluation_loss = 9999

    def after_save(self, run_context, run_values):
        print("--- done writing checkpoint. ---")
        evaluation = self._estimator.evaluate(input_fn=self._input_fn)
        print(evaluation)
        if evaluation['loss'] < self._evaluation_loss:
            self._evaluation_loss = evaluation['loss']
        else:
            return True # Stop Training
```

When Training:

```
early_stopping = tf.contrib.estimator.stop_if_no_decrease_hook(
    hard_estimator,
    metric_name='loss',
    max_steps_without_decrease=500,
    min_steps=100)

monitor_validation = ValidationListener(estimator=hard_estimator, input_fn=hard_validation_input_fn)

hard_estimator.train(
    input_fn = train_input_fn,
    hooks=[early_stopping],
    steps=1000,
    saving_listeners=[monitor_validation]
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. How does this work in distributed training in a multi-GPU single machine setting?

Comment: According to the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/experimental/stop_if_no_decrease_hook , Caveat: Current implementation supports early-stopping both training and evaluation in local mode. In distributed mode, training can be stopped but evaluation (where it's a separate job) will indefinitely wait for new model checkpoints to evaluate, so you will need other means to detect and stop it. Early-stopping evaluation in distributed mode requires changes in train_and_evaluate API and will be addressed in a future revision.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to validate the training after every n_steps, tf will use the latest saved checkpoint. You can use a custom `CheckpointSaverListener` class to add the evaluation step after the checkpoint is saved using `CheckpointSaverHook`.
Pass the model classifier object and evaluation input function to the class

Reference https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/CheckpointSaverListener

```
class ExampleCheckpointSaverListener(CheckpointSaverListener):
  def __init(self):
    self.classifier = classifier
    self.eval_input_fn = eval_input_fn

  def begin(self):
    # You can add ops to the graph here.
    print('Starting the session.')
    self.your_tensor = ...

  def before_save(self, session, global_step_value):
    print('About to write a checkpoint')
    eval_op = self.classifier.evaluate(input_fn=self.eval_input_fn)
    print(eval_op)

  def after_save(self, session, global_step_value):
    print('Done writing checkpoint.')

  def end(self, session, global_step_value):
    print('Done with the session.')

...
listener = ExampleCheckpointSaverListener(Myclassifier, eval_input_fn )
saver_hook = tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook(
    checkpoint_dir, listeners=[listener])
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(chief_only_hooks=[saver_hook]):
```