# validation during training of Estimator

Tags: tensorflow

With the TensorFlow r1.3 monitors are deprecated:

"2016-12-05",
      "Monitors are deprecated. Please use tf.train.SessionRunHook.")
and Estimator.train(input_fn,hooks,..) works only with hooks.

How to implement the functionality of validation monitor with hooks?

Comment: What version do you consider "current"?

Comment: TensorFlow r1.3, but the problem starts since TensorFlow 1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using `SummarySaverHook` instead of Monitors. They are not "as powerful" just yet, and the training material has not been updated with a description on how exactly replicate the Monitor functionality.

Here is how i use it:

```
summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(
    save_steps=SAVE_EVERY_N_STEPS,
    output_dir='./tmp/rnnStats',
    scaffold=tf.train.Scaffold(),
    summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())

print("Classifier.train")
classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=1000, hooks=[summary_hook])
```

Comment: How would you do a validation on a separate dataset with your solution?

Comment: you may want to checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793703/replace-validation-monitors-with-tf-train-sessionrunhook-when-using-estimators

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments, this feels like the right thing to do, *but* will reinitialize the weights every time it's evaluated, which makes it pretty much useless...

---

I ended up being able to monitor my validation error (which is what I understand you are trying to do) using the [`train_and_evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate) function. The [`EvalSpec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EvalSpec) object you have to use has parameters `start_delay_secs` and `throttle_secs` to define the frequency at which the error (or whatever you have defined in your estimator's `EVAL` mode) will be computed.

My code looks somewhat like

```py
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    model_dir=model_dir,
    params=params)

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
    input_fn = input_fn,
)

eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
    input_fn = valid_input_fn,
    throttle_secs=120,
    start_delay_secs=120,
)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(
    classifier,
    train_spec,
    eval_spec
)
```

Comment: Hi simlmx, we tried the same but it seems that the net gets reloaded with initial weights for every evaluation when the hook fires in.
Did you experience the same? Ideally we'd like to evaluate the network with its current weights without reloading anything, just the input_fn should change.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I experienced the same thing. I'm not sure but I think it didn't restart from initial weights, but rather from the last time it was saved. I tried to work around that by saving the model more often so that the problem wouldn't be as bad, but I ended up getting tired of `Estimator`s altogether and returned to more "classical" `tensorflow`.