# Tensorflow Estimator - Periodic Evaluation on Eval Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

The tensorflow documentation does not provide any example of how to perform a periodic evaluation of the model on an evaluation set.

[Some people](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7669) suggested the use of an Experiment, which sounds great but unfortunately does not work (depreciation and triggers an error).

[Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417502/validation-during-training-of-estimator?noredirect=1#comment77798445_45417502) suggested the use of SummarySaverHook, but I don't see how you can use that with an evaluation set (as opposed to the training set).

A solution would be to do the following

```
for i in range(number_of_epoch):
    estimator.train(...) // on training set
    estimator.evaluate(...) // on evaluation set
```

This architecture is explicitly discouraged in [this paper](https://terrytangyuan.github.io/data/papers/tf-estimators-kdd-paper.pdf) (page 4 top right).

Any other idea/implementation?

EDIT:

The error message when running the experiment is the following:

```
File ".../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 253, in train if (config.environment != run_config.Environment.LOCAL and
AttributeError: 'RunConfig' object has no attribute 'environment'
```

Tensorflow version 1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a few parameters/options of `Experiment` are deprecated (what specific errors are you seeing?). If you create an `Estimator` that will do periodic checkpoints (using options in [RunConfig](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/RunConfig)) and an `Experiment` using it, you will get evaluation for each checkpoint by default when using [`train_and_evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment) method.

EDIT: As Maxime pointed out in the comments. He needed to add the following lines to get rid of his error:

```
os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps({'environment': 'local'})
config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the question with the error log. The error message I get is: "AttributeError: 'RunConfig' object has no attribute 'environment'"

Comment: I will try adding this: 
    os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps({'environment': 'local'})
    config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig()

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. Could you edit your answer and add the two lines of code so everyone can understand?

Comment: How is that it worked? In [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment) clearly says that the Experiment class is deprecated. Please see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619995/how-to-log-metrics-on-a-validation-set-using-the-estimator-api-of-tensorflow)

Comment: The whole class has been deprecated very recently, before this question. Here is a starting point to migrating from Experiment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.7/tensorflow/contrib/learn/README.md#experiment-class---distributed-training-tooling