# Compute precision/recall for tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have just updated the `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier` to use `tf.estimator`, which only takes `SessionRunHook` not a `ValidationMonitor`, I have been using the code described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/get_started/monitors) to compute precision/recall as the evaluator does not print those two metrics. However, I cannot find a way to implement the same thing using `SessionRunHook` required for `tf.estimator.Estimator`.

I found a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793703/replace-validation-monitors-with-tf-train-sessionrunhook-when-using-estimators), but it seems that in the code it is specifically disabled to use `ValidationMonitor` if metrics is specified (from tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py):

```
if isinstance(self._estimator, core_estimator.Estimator):
  if any((x is not None for x in
          [self.x, self.y, self.batch_size, self.metrics])):
    raise ValueError(
        "tf.estimator.Estimator does not support following "
        "arguments: x, y, batch_size, metrics. Should set as `None` "
        "in ValidationMonitor")
```

I am using tensorflow 1.5.0.

Any suggestion how this can be implemented?

Comment: for me instantiating the validation monitor with an input_fn instead of passing explicitly x_val and y_val worked to get rid of the same error. using tensorflow 1.5 as well.