# Evaluate every N steps using tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Is there some way for TensorFlow to automatically evaluate on an evaluation set every N steps of training using the `tf.data.Dataset` API? Currently, my input functions look like this:

```
def train_input_fn():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(train_x), train_y))

    return (
        dataset
        .repeat()
        .shuffle(len(train_x) * 1.33))
        .batch(128)
        .make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    )

def eval_input_fn():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(eval_x), eval_y))

    return (
        dataset
        .batch(len(eval_x)) # to use the entire eval set
        .make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    )
```

and they are called on an instance of `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor` like this:

```
est = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(...)

est.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=5000)
est.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the deprecated `tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor`, as suggested [in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793703/replace-validation-monitors-with-tf-train-sessionrunhook-when-using-estimators). The `ValidationMonitor` can still be used on an `Estimator` using the `monitors.replace_monitors_with_hooks` utility function.

Here is my implementation:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import monitors as monitor_lib

est = tf.Estimator.DNNRegressor(...)

validation_monitor = tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(
    input_fn=eval_input_fn,
    every_n_steps=100,
)
list_of_monitors_and_hooks = [validation_monitor]
hooks = monitor_lib.replace_monitors_with_hooks(list_of_monitors_and_hooks, est)

est.train(
    input_fn=input_fn_train,
    steps=1000,
    hooks=hooks
)
```

Comment: Please note that the `every_n_steps` argument to `ValidationMonitor` checks for new checkpoints to evaluate every N steps. Therefore, you would also need to pass a custom `RunConfig` to the default `tf.train.DNNRegressor` so that checkpoints are saved more frequently:

    `est = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(..., config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=100))`